# jQuery Overlay/Slide Div Implementation!

Tags: jquery-ui, html

I'm trying out something in jQuery and stumbled upon a site

http://pupunzi.com/, on this site, the left hand side has two buttons, when you click on either of them, there is a overlay window on the right hand side that's created.

How do I implement a thing like that!!

NOTE: This might be a wrong place to ask, please ignore is so and let me know, so shall delete this query.

Comment: that site runs my CPU utilization to 70% just on page changes... lol.. running a 3.0ghz core2duo too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [tabSlideOut jQuery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/tab-slide-out) is what I was looking for...

Answer (score 2):

If you keep looking, you'll find that they have written that effect as a plugin for jQuery and you can view and download it from the very website you've spotted it on!

http://pupunzi.com/

Look for the absolutely massive mb.jquery.components link on the home page.

Comment: @Sohnee: mb.jquery.components package does not contain that kind of work, I check the source and its pointing to some patapage.com and they have some license on it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like they are using something like [Facebox](https://github.com/defunkt/facebox) or [BlockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/)